# Cygwin <=> GCC version mapping?

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I cannot find a mapping between Cygwin and corresponding GCC version numbers.

Can anyone provide a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one.

You can use the cygwin announce mailing list
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/
to see the temporal releases of the two packages.

Please note that the only version supported is the last one,
so if you try to use old versions you are on your own.

Comment: Cygwin doesn't support current gcc releases unless you build it yourself but the same is true for typical linux.